# Exim sending from multiple ip's balance by number of sent mails

Tags: exim

I have an exim mail server with 5 IP addresses. I have setup it to send mails using the 5 IPs.

I have followed this link: [Exim4 configuration to use several external ip for mail sending](https://serverfault.com/questions/355313/exim4-configuration-to-use-several-external-ip-for-mail-sending)

Now I use the randint function to choose the IPs, but there is a way to choose a different IP every X mails that are sent?